# Calculate the power being supplied to the circuit by the controlled current source shown in FIGURE Q3

Tags: power

I can't figure how i am meant to tackle this question with loop method or do we just take i1 to be -9A?
any help would be appreciated!!!

Calculate the power being supplied to the circuit by the controlled current source shown in FIGURE Q3.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equation for I:

$$6 + 2I_1 - I_1 - 9 = 0$$

Then calculate the power dissipated in the 3 Ohm resistor:

$$P = I_1^2 \times 3\;Ohm$$

This is the power supplied.  Ideal current sources by themselves dissipate no power, the only power here is dissipated by the resistor.